# Unkown attack on linux server wordpress website

Tags: attacks, apache, ddos, wordpress

I have a WordPress site. Recently under a serious DDoS attack.

For this WordPress site I use nginx, varnish and apache in the backend.

A part of access log shows this:

```
24.41.213.36 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:13 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
88.255.108.4 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
189.157.252.135 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 588 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
155.232.186.14 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
27.147.183.238 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
186.167.66.149 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
186.167.66.149 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
103.248.119.141 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
202.62.49.119 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:14 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
177.44.175.204 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:15 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 588 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
14.102.76.42 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:15 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
181.113.225.198 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:15 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
202.51.103.82 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:15 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
88.12.48.61 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:15 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla /4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
84.243.197.97 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:15 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)" 
45.234.144.106 - - [23/Jun/2019:12:58:15 +0430] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 588 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbPTV/5.15.1.22229; BOIE9;ENUS;CloudVersion)"
```

Do you have any idea for this attack?

Comment: I see only `GET /`, why do you think it's an attack? What did the request look like to get HTTP 400? What caused the HTTP 500?

Comment: `GET`s do not look like a DoS attack, and 8 requests in a minute are certainly not a DDoS attack. If it was a DDoS attack, I'm not sure what you are asking. Ideas about *what*?

Comment: true log should be something such as the following:
37.98.68.156 GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/04/xx.png HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://r.yxzyxz.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-A320F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.99 Mobile Safari/537.36"
But it seems our Nginx logs were not Normal during attack time! How should we find out what domains are requested from these messy logs?
Moreover, suddenly the server bw increased from normal range 10-20 Mbs to around 500Mbs and the Nginx connections increased to 6000 which was 10 times more than the usual time as well.

Comment: This was just a few requests to view.
Requests from all over the world IP were sent to the server.
Thousands of requests have been received with the same structure in Nginx logs.

Comment: Please edit your question to include these details. You also need to answer the question about what you are asking about. Do we have an idea? Yes. You are being DDoSed. Is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: The number of characters is limited for additional descriptions.
I want to know if I can block these requests? What level should be done?

Comment: If you just want to block those requests then ModSecurity comes in handy. You can block such requests based on user-agent.